# Query to Rename Tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005 I am looking to rename a lot of tables using a wildcard,
for example, the table names are:

```
OrderItem
OrderItems
OrderItemss
```

I would like them to be renamed to:

```
OrderItem2
OrderItems2
OrderItemss2
```

Can this be done using a wildcard so I don't have to specify the full table name? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the system tables to select all table names matching you pattern, e.g. 'OrderItem%', or more sophisticated. Then using dynamic sql to update the names using the `exec SP_RENAME 'old_name' 'new_name'`.

However, this will not take effect on stored procedures querying the tables.  Those stored procedures will need to be recompiled after the rename is complete.

**Solution Sql**

Okay, here is the entire code. It is based on that table names starts with "OrderItem" and that they all shall have the original name with "2" postfixed. I create a table variable holding the found tables before renaming them. If you "uncomment" the select statement and only execute down to that statement you can see what tables are select to be renamed, and to what they will be renamed. **NOTE** that i am only selecting tables from the dbo schema.

```
declare @OldTableName nvarchar(max)
declare @NewTableName nvarchar(max)
declare @SqlStmt nvarchar(max)

declare @Tables table
(
    OldTableName nvarchar(max),
    NewTableName nvarchar(max)
)

insert into @Tables (OldTableName, NewTableName)
select
    name as OldTableName ,
    name + '2' as NewTableName
from sys.tables
where name like 'OrderItem%'
    and schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')

-- select * from @Tables

declare cur cursor for
select OldTableName,
NewTableName
from @Tables

open cur
while (1=1)
begin

    fetch next from cur into @OldTableName, @NewTableName

    if @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        break

    set @SqlStmt = N'sp_rename ''' + @OldTableName + ''', ''' + @NewTableName + ''''

    exec sp_executesql @SqlStmt

end

close cur
deallocate cur
```

**NEW 24apr2013**

Select statement that includes the schema name and not only looks in `dbo` schema

```
select
    s.name + '.' + t.name as OldTableName,
    t.name + '2' as NewTableName
from sys.tables as t
inner join sys.schemas as s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where t.name like 'OrderItem%'
```

**Added**

Look in `sys.tables` for all tables (remember to only select those in the schema you want to rename). Insert the names into a temporary table, along with the new table names you give them, then iterate over each of them generating a sql string with the call to the `sp_rename` and use the `exec sp_executesql 'SQL STMT'` to make the actual execution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am not looking to just rename the tables. I have to do this process for many tables, I am asking if I can do this with a wildcard so I don't have to specify the full table name for tables that begin with the same letter.

Comment: That is what i am suggesting. You select all the tabels in the `sys.table` matching youre wildcard, and rename them!

Comment: thanks for the follow up.  I able to run the code without an error now.  I am not sure how to execute the second part. Can you elaborate on how to iterate over each of them with call sp_rename?

Comment: You need to execute all the code above at once to perform the rename. I am getting the feeling that you are not very familiar with SQL, right? Maybe you should take a look at some basic tutorials/lessons just to get the very basic.

Comment: this the first thing someone learns in a basic SQL tutorial/lesson?  Can you please post a link to this basic SQL lesson so I can review before posting. thanks

Comment: Here are some links, these two are on the sql language, [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) and [SQL tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm) and this is more on [execution plans](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9990/SQL-Tuning-Tutorial-Understanding-a-Database-Execu). These are just some examples (google finds many other good tutorials). Just play a bit around and get a feeling with sql to understand what and how to execute statements.

Comment: I was being facetious. w3schools.com isn't going to assist in knowing how to do what I am asking but thanks.

Comment: And i was literal :) as the code above is the entire code to rename all youre tables i don't understand what about part two to explain. It iterates over each found table and rename it, that is it. Have you tested it and did it solve the problem?

Comment: I think I see where I was running into a problem.  The full table name is Customers.OrderItems I am used to working with an older version of SQL and with this version SQL 2005 when I ran select * from sys.tables to get back the tables in the database it would only show OrderItems, not Customers.OrderItems.  So when I tried to run the SP_RENAME it would throw an error if I just referenced OrderItems.

Comment: Okay, i assume that the `customer` part of the name is the schema the table is stored in? The code example i gave only looks in the `dbo`shcmea, which is this line `schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')`. I have added an select statement that includes the schema name in the search, maybe that is helpfull?

Comment: I think I have what I need now. As long as I have the proper table names for all the tables I can create the script in Excel and then run the store procedure. I did try the alter code above and it ran fine but as someone suggested on another post you can break the functionality of the database.  This is only a test system. Thanks for all the help.  Do I need to close out the post ? I didn't see how to do this.

Comment: You can select (accept) the answer you liked, by clicking the green checkmark right under the up/down votes next to the actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's this simple:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);

SELECT
   @SQL = Coalesce(@SQL + Char(13) + Char(10), '') + 'EXEC sp_rename '''
   + Replace(QuoteName(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QuoteName(TABLE_NAME), '''', '''''')
   + ''', ''' + Replace(TABLE_NAME + '2', '''', '''''') + ''';'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
WHERE
   T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
   AND T.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'OrderItem%'
;

EXEC (@SQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of all the user tables filtered by what you need for example with this query:

```
select name from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name like 'user%'
```

then use the `sp_executesql` and a cursor to the results of the query to execute dynamic SQL ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)) to perform the actual renaming.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, I would recommend using the *more targeted* catalog views like `sys.tables` instead of just always using the "catch all" `sysobjects` (and btw: `sysobjects` is deprecated in 2005 - use `sys.objects` if you must)

Comment: marc_s I figured out why I was having an issue running a few of the select commands to reference the tables.Using sys.tables- It was only bringing back the second part the table name. The full table name is Customers.OrderItems.I work with an older version of SQL2000 and I don't usually see table names like this.So I know renaming tables isn't advised but I am only doing this to learn and have to merge databases with the same table name. But based on aweis comment it looks like I have to go back and read a basic tutorial 1st. For now I will wait for the SQL Lesson link from  Aewis. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

first that all find the number of tables in your data base (I have 3)
and put this code in a stored procedure, also it can put parameters!!

```
 `alter procedure [dbo].[changetableName]
  as
  declare @sql varchar(8000), @table varchar(1000), @oldTable varchar(1000),  
  @newTable     
  varchar(1000);
  declare @Inc integer;
  set @Inc=1;

  set @oldTable = '%OrderItem%'
  set @newTable = 'OrderItem_n'

  while exists(SELECT object_id, t.name AS table_name FROM sys.tables AS t where
  t.name Like @oldTable) and (@Inc<=3)
   begin

    select @table = name from sys.tables 
   where object_id in(select object_id from sys.tables as t where t.name like 
        @oldTable )

 set @sql = 'sp_rename ' + @table + ' , ' + @newTable + CONVERT(varchar(2),@Inc) 

    exec(@sql)
   SET @Inc = @Inc + 1;
  select @sql
  end`
```

Comment: Note that you are assigning the tables a new name that still matches the pattern, hence you can potentially hit on the same table multiple times as you keep using the sys.table in the loop.